# Riged bodies not coming to rest and falling through each other

Tags: modeling, rigid-body-simulation

I  am having trouble with a small animation.  All I wan to do is have the wine bottle sit in the rack so that I can tip it over and have the bottle fall out, but the bottle will not even sit in the rack without slipping through the rack mesh.  The rack and floor is passive and the bottle is active with deactivation turn on.  Any help is appreciated.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the colisión type turned from "convex hill" to mesh?

Comment: Further to @leo's comment, are your normals all pointing in the right direction (outwards). Should also Apply Scale and possibly increase the number of simulation 'steps'.

Comment: Yes, mesh type is set on both objects.  Not sure how to increase animation steps . ??

Comment: Read the stability part of this : https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/rigid_body/tips.html

Comment: I can get it to partially work by setting the wine bottle body to Convex Hull.  Still not the result I hoped for.

Comment: on the scene tab increase the Rigid Body World - Steps Per Second and Solver Iterations. It will slow everything down but make it more accurate. Also on the Physics tab for the bottle object check Enable Deactivated and Start Deactivated.